# how to include bootstrap css file in zend framework 1.12

Tags: php, css, zend-framework

I have a zend framework application up and running. I have created a layout. Now I need to include bootstrap css file to my layout.

I tried with 'baseUrl' but it didn't work. I have the css files inside 'public/assets/css'.

I also tried with tutorial in zend framework website. But it didn't work.

They mentioned to use

```
<?php echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/assets/css/bootstrap.css') ?>
```

I added the above line in layout page but it didn't work.

Also for your information when I use this headlink, in console it's showing as

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:8010/assets/css/bootstrap.css".
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Head Tag:**

```
<head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Zend Framework Quickstart Application</title> 
    <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
</head>
```

Extra information: I have a controller 'HomeController' in it I have defined an action

```
public function homeTwoAction()
    {
        // action body
        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');

    }
```

In views -> I have home-two.phtml inside 'scripts/home'.

In layout I have the following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Bootstrap</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap.min.css">-->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/customstyle.css">-->
    <!--<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/customstyle.css">-->
    <?= $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/assets/css/customstyle.css') ?>
    <?= $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') ?>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am accessing

```
http://localhost:8010/home/home-two
```

HTML content is loaded but css not loading. Thanks.

Comment: Post the content of the head tag when the page loads. And what server are you using? Apache?

Comment: `<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Zend Framework Quickstart Application</title>
          <link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">      
</head>`
Netbeans inbuilt server

Comment: You need to configure your server to serve has files with appropriate mime type

Comment: Thanks for the response Neil Patrao. Do I need to configure it in Netbeans web server?

Comment: Yes..in Netbeans

Comment: What I need to change? Can you please explain?

Comment: What I also notice is that you posted the error for `pagestyle.css` but your head tag includes just the `bootstrap.css` file

Comment: Sorry that was my fault. It shows the same error for both files when added.

Comment: This message appear when CSS file is not found. You put your CSS file in wrong folder (or your link is wrong).

Comment: Please see content below 'Extra information: ' in the question. I have added it for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Changing Mime type is explained [here](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/file_types_UI_spec/)

1. Go to Tools -> Options
2. Then under `Miscellaneous` tab choose the file type `css`  and make sure the `Associated File Type` is `text/css`

### Edit

Try opening http://localhost:8010/assets/css/ or http://localhost:8010/assets/ what do you see?

Comment: For your information: when I open this link `http://localhost:8010/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` it doesn't open the css file instead it opens a page.

Comment: It shows the Welcome to Zend Framework page's content and the html I added in `home-two.phtml` file.

Comment: Open the links above and post in your question what you see

Comment: It's showing as `An error occurred` `Page not found`

Comment: Did you add the assets folder through netbeans IDE or Windows explorer..?

Comment: I am using centos 7 [linux]. I added the assets folder manually by 'New Folder' option.